# MS Exchange Transport Rules - set transport rule using specific text patterns

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I'm adding a transport rule that filters for incoming messages whose specific sender address contains a specific subject string. This is 2013 on-prem.
So I mean , This rule only will to work when "Transfer Flow" is the entire subject line.
It will not work when it is part of the subject line such as "New Email Transfer Flow" or "Hello Transfer Flow" or "Transfer Flow Order".

```
Apply this rule if...
  The Sender is ..  ->> user01@contoso.com
and
the recipient is ... -->> user02@contoso.com
and
The subject or body - subject matches text patterns "Transfer Flow"

Do the following
Cc the message to ->> user03@contoso.com
```

I could really use some help. I'm pulling my hair out here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research and testing in my lab, there seems to be no way to meet your request.

I found a similar thread, which provided to use regular expressions to configure transport rule to meet your issue, and I tested in my lab via following the steps in this thread, I got nothing. I post this [thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1975387-ms-exchange-transport-rules-using-regular-expressions) for your reference, may be helpful to you.